# How to register custom installer with Windows Add/Remove programs?

Tags: c#, windows, installation, addremoveprograms

I want to create a custom installer (as opposed to using a Windows Installer package). However, I also want to be able to have the custom installer application appear in the Add/Remove programs list so that the uninstall is easy. How do I do this?

Comment: The better, you use InstallShield.

Comment: Don't do this. There is a number of alternatives out there, both free and commercial, which can do it much better way out of the box. Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Why are you tagging this windows-installer if you aren't making a windows-installer package?